# How to use custom middleware with Laravel 404 exception

Tags: laravel-5, httpexception

In my Laravel 5.2 app I have custom middleware called 'cart' that I use to keep track of the users cart contents across different routes.

It looks like this:

```
class CartMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $cart = new Cart();
        $cart_total = $cart->total();

        view()->composer(['layouts.main'], function ($view) use ($cart_total) {
        $view->with('cart_total', $cart_total);
    });
    return $next($request);
}
```

}

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cart']], function () {
    Route::get('cart', 'CartController@show');
});
```

When ever my app raises a 404 exception the 404.blade.php view cannot render because it is missing the `$cart_total` that is supplied by the 'cart' middleware.

Is there a way to assign this 'cart' middleware to my exception?

```
  if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Found'], 404);
        }
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not storing this value in the session?

Comment: Instead of `layouts.main` you can try to use `partials.cart-stats` like `view()->composer('partials.cart-stats', function($view) use ($cart_total){$view->with('cart_total', $cart_total);});` and then `@include('partials.cart-stats')` maybe in a hidden `div` in both `layouts.main` as well as all your custom error pages for ex `404.blade.php`. However better way would be store your cart values in session.

Comment: Placing the $cart_total into a view partial is a good idea, but I don't see how that fixes the issue. The cart is in the session, the middleware makes it available to the layout as the cart->class parses the cart data. I will look into creating a simple cart_total session variable that doesn't require parsing. Thanks for insight.

Comment: I tested the code by placing the $cart_total in a view partial and then include that partial in all custom error pages as well - in a hidden div. The error pages are displayed without any hitch whenever there is a corresponding exception.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up removing the CartMiddleware entirely, and handling the session updates when the cart is changed. This was my fix.

Answer (score 0):

At Laravel 5.4 and probably some older ones you can modify the file `app/exceptions/Handler.php` and the function `render` like this:

```
if( is_a( $exception, \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException::class ) ) {
    return redirect()->route( 'error_404' );
}

// ... old code in the function ...
```

in this way every 404 errors are redirected to certain real route that acts like other routes of site.

You may also submit any data from current request to show a reasonable error at the target.